# Push view controller logic error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

Im wondering if someone can please tell me what am I missing. I got a tableview with two sections, but when I tap onto anything on section 2, content from section 1 cells is loaded.
Thanks in advance.

here is my didselectrowatindexpath:

```
    UIViewController *targetViewController = [[views objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]     objectForKey:@"controller"];
   [[self navigationController] pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];

if (indexPath.section == 0)
      [partA  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    else 
      [partB objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      [targetViewController release];
}
```

Comment: btw You're releasing an object [targetViewController release] you didn't create or retain. objectForKey returns autoreleased object from NSDictionary...

Answer (score 0):

In your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, you may not be accounting for the section; i.e. you're pulling a `UIViewController` from the `views` array using `indexPath.row`, when you should probably also be using `indexPath.section` as a qualifier. It's hard to give a better answer without seeing more of your view controller.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll change indexPath.row for indexPath.section to see results and post my results.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use following code instead of your if statement.

```
UITableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Also remove the release because you did not retain or allocate it.

But honest: I do not understand what you want to do. What do you mean by "loaded"? Loaded where?

Comment: Sorry I didnt make myself clear, by "loaded" I meant pushing an accesory view for each component "partA section & partB section"; so when I sectioned the table view, section two (partB objectAtIndex...) loads the content for partA.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided it but my guess is that you should override didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and check the owner of the selecting cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

{

if ( tableView == _tableView1){

     //Do something
}

else if ( tableView == _tableView2){

     //Do something different
}

else return;
```